# Is it possible to set SpringBootTest properties on the fly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

I have a SpringBoot application which I am trying to test with the help of [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/). I have something like:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class DummyIT {

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer();

    static {
        postgreSQLContainer.start();
        String url = postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(); 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately Testcontainers use random ports and if I understood correctly we are not supposed to have it any other way, which means that the result of `postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl()` is not deterministic.

Moreover, my application retrieves the database url from its `application.properties` and I was aiming at replacing such value from the one provided by `postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl()`, before it is first used during runtime. Is it possible to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the anwser is described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Testcontainers JDBC URL support](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/#database-containers-launched-via-jdbc-url-scheme).

For example,

```
@SpringBootTest(
   properties = {
      "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8://localhost/your-database",
      "spring.datasource.username=dummy-user",
      "spring.datasource.password=dummy-password",
      "spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect",
      "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver"
})
public class DummyIT {
}
```

The Testcontainers driver `ContainerDatabaseDriver` will create and start a PostgreSQL server 9.6.8 with a database named `your-database`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it first thing on Monday!